# How to copy values from one column to another same table SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

I want to copy value from `OrderNbr` to `OrigOrderNbr` that are in the same table but different type as SO and QT.

I want to update `OrigOrderNbr` (QT type) from `OrderNbr` (SO type) and SO is created after QT. Other ways to explain is when I create quotation and then I converted it to SOOrder. I want to update QT OrigOrderNbr after SO is inserted.

Can I do that?

[image]

Comment: I mean SO is SOOrder and QT is Quotation.

Comment: Need more info, please - what are the SQL data types of each column? Do you want to copy manually (one-time operation), or each time a new record is inserted? Please update your question with these details, and also show what you've tried so far.

Comment: @Elina do you mean to say that whenever OrderType or OrigOrderType is QT or SO  copy value from OrderNbr to OrigOrderNbr ???

Comment: Sorry for unclear question. But I mean I want to update OrigOrderNbr (QT type) from OrderNbr (SO type) and SO is created after QT. Other ways to explain is when I create quotation and then I converted it to SOOrder. I want to update QT OrigOrderNbr after SO is inserted. Can I do that?

Comment: @Elina sure, isn't there a stored procedure that handles the conversion from quotation to sales order? You can handle it there, or via a trigger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways to handle this: within stored procedure or query that is converting Quotation to Sales Order (preferred method), or via a Trigger on the table (works, but has side effects - for instance, will trigger on manual inserts/updates)

It's hard to help you further without seeing the SQL code responsible for conversion of Quotation to Sales Order.

Comment: Yes, I'm working on trigger right now. Thanks your messages :)

Comment: here is my trigger:

Comment: @Elina I can't see the trigger code in your last comment, but If you have a question related to the trigger, please post a new question with relevant code and detailed description.

Comment: I already posted the others question in tag: sql-server, but not yet get the answer.

Comment: @Elina I found your new post, will try to help you there.